# Atomic file change with two operations

Tags: linux, file

I need to do two operations on one file.

1. add a line at the end
2. remove for example the 3rd line

These two options need to be atomic, that means, either both operations should be done, or none of them in case any of them is failing.

Any ideas how to accomplish this on a Linux environment?

The only idea coming in my mind is make a copy of the file, modify it, and if it succeeds, replace it with the original.

Comment: I agree with your only idea, I just have the same. But it not perfectly atomic: you can safely prepare the new file, but then you need to unlink the old one to rename the new one. And a crash could occur between the delete and the rename. But anyway, I know no better way...

Comment: @SergeBallesta, `rename()` is atomic, and it makes the old file to lose the name. The old file then disappears if not open.